# Cannot find restaurant using /venue/search end-point

Tags: foursquare

Question to Foursquare engineers :) Could you please explain to me why I cannot find restaurant using `/venue/search` end-point ?

Restaurant in question is [Aqua in San Francisco](https://foursquare.com/v/aqua/3fd66200f964a52014ed1ee3). According to [/venue/ID](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/3fd66200f964a52014ed1ee3?v=20130712&oauth_token=QEJ4AQPTMMNB413HGNZ5YDMJSHTOHZHMLZCAQCCLXIX41OMP) request restaurant location is 37.793489,-122.399905. So I'm calling /venue/search request with intent=checkin with exactly these coordinates.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?v=20130712&ll=37.793489,-122.399905&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259&intent=checkin&radius=100&oauth_token=QEJ4AQPTMMNB413HGNZ5YDMJSHTOHZHMLZCAQCCLXIX41OMP

API returns me 30 items with no Aqua in it. Where as in [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) it says:

`Unlike the checkin intent, browse searches an entire region instead of only finding Venues closest to a point.`

So then why doesn't it return items sorted by the distance from the point I provided?

If I change intent to browse I'll get "Aqua" in results.

Basically behavior looks inconsistent. How can I make it more reliable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is happening because this isn't a venue that Foursquare thinks you're likely to check in at. Given your lat/lon and radius, Foursquare thinks that you're more likely to check in to the 30 results you see than the restaurant you have in mind.

However, if you either reduce the radius or increase the number of results, you'll find the restaurant in question.

Comment: That's true. There is one problem in increasing the radius though - in highly populated areas number of restaurants within given radius may exceed maximum number of returned items.

Comment: I suggested decreasing the radius to focus on the area, not increase it :) Indeed the problem with your particular example is that there are too many restaurants around, and the one you're looking for isn't bubbling up.

Comment: Hate to say it but...  This is not true.